# Java run Main Method inside Java Program do not exit afterwards

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Hi I use the following code [to run main method with args from another jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512748/how-to-run-main-method-with-args-from-another-jar):

```
import com.foo.bar.MainApp;

class MyInitClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // call second main method
        MainApp.main(new String[] {"-port", "8080"});

        // this code gets never executed
        System.out.println("Never gets called");
    }
}
```

The nested `main(new String[] {"-port", "8080"})` method gets executed but then the whole program gracefully exits.

How can I continue that the `System.out.println` gets also executed.

Comment: What does the other main method do? If it calls `System.exit()`, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Try wrapping it in an exception handler and see if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @SteveSmith it "exits gracefully". if an exception were thrown, and not caught, that wouldn't be the case

Comment: You might check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api if the called main does a `System.exit()`

Comment: @Stultuske True, didn't spot that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong on how you execute the main method of the MainApp, Then like @Seelenvirtuose the second class might have called a `System.exit()`.

Comment: If you just want to execute the next line after the cal of `MainApp.main(new String[] {"-port", "8080"});` then why not use Async call?

Comment: The problem is that the main method in the .jar file calles "System.exit()" so I have to change the source code of the jar file. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the main method in the .jar file calles "System.exit()" so I have to change the source code of the jar file. Thanks for pointing that out.

[image]